# Make node REPL reload imported module on file change?

Tags: node.js, module, read-eval-print-loop

New to node - want to prototype fast. 
Have defined a module in `index.js`.
I start the node REPL, by typing `node`. 
Then, i require the module: `var index = require('./index')`

Now, i want the module to be re-imported each time i make a change to it. Is there any out-of-the-box solution for this?